# contenteditable to textfile in azure storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, blob

i am trying to convert the content of an editable div to a text file and store it in azure. It's actually a css file (format) but i guess that text will have the same output. This is what i got so far:\

```
var sasKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var blobUri = xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey);

function Save() {

    var blobData = document.getElementById("CONTENT").innerText;
    var myBlob = new Blob(blobData, "plain/text");

    blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile('style',
        "test.txt",
        myBlob,
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle blob error
            } else {    
                console.log('Upload is successful');
            }
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="CONTENT" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">so here we have text</div>

<input type="button" value="save" onclick="Save()"/>
```

i get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Blob`object takes a list as its first parameter.

Try this instead:

```
var myBlob = new Blob([blobData], { type: "plain/text" });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

Comment: thanks, this actually converted the blob in a file. However as it turned out, i did not need the conversion. Azure does this automatically with the createBlockBlobFromText that just accepts any string.

Answer (score 0):

to be complete this is what i used to upload a text (txt) file

```
<script>azure-storage.blob.min.js</script>
```

JS

```
var sasKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var blobUri = xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, sasKey);

function Save() {

    var blobData = document.getElementById("CONTENT").innerText;

    blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('container', (error, container) => {
        if (error) {
            // Handle create container error
        } else {
            console.log(container.name);
        }
    });

    blobService.createBlockBlobFromText('container', "test.txt", blobData,
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle blob error
            } else {    
                console.log('Upload is successful');
            }
        });
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="CONTENT" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">so here we have text</div>

<input type="button" value="save" onclick="Save()"/>
```